# Compare two strings with wildcard

Tags: vb.net

I want to compare two strings. I want to be able to say that s1 is equal to s2 because of the common word "hello". any suggestions on how to achieve this with or without another function?

```
s1: hello
s2: hello world

if s1 = s2 then
       ..do something
else
       ..do something
end if
```

Comment: That's very unclear.  What if they both have the letter `e`? Or a space?

Comment: don't matter, as long as it has the word "hello" in it, I want to say both is equal.

Comment: So call `.Contains("Hello")`?

Comment: you beat me to it SLacks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds as if you want to compare substrings, you can use `String.Contains`:

```
Dim s1 = "hello"
Dim s2 = "hello world"

Dim s2ContainsHello As Boolean = s2.Contains(s1) ' True
```

or (if you want to ignore the case) `String.IndexOf` which returns -1 if it wasn't found:

```
s2 = "Hello World"
s2ContainsHello = s2.IndexOf(s1, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0 ' Still True
```

a third option in VB.NET is to use the `Like` operator (which also is case-sensitive by default):

```
s2ContainsHello = s2 like "*" & s1 & "*"
```

The [`Like`-operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx) supports wild-cards:

```
Characters in pattern    Matches in string
?                        Any single character
*                        Zero or more characters
#                        Any single digit (0–9)
[charlist]               Any single character in charlist
[!charlist]              Any single character not in charlist
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're just looking for whether or not both strings have "hello" somewhere in them

```
If s1.Contains("hello") AndAlso s2.Contains("hello") Then
    'do something
Else
    'do something else
End If
```