# VB.Net Regex to match with a given string

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have 2 Arrays of strings as below (B is subset of A) and trying to pull the matched elements on B from A

```
A = ["1.1","1.1.1","1.1.2","1.1.3","1.2","1.3","1.4",....]
B = ["1.1.*","1.2"]

This should return ["1.1.1","1.1.2","1.1.3","1.2"]
```

My sample attempt to solve this problem:

```
Dim regEx As New Regex("1.1.*")
Console.WriteLine(regEx.IsMatch("1.1.1"))   'TRUE which is Expected
Console.WriteLine(regEx.IsMatch("1.1"))     'TRUE - Expected is FALSE
```

Comment: `.*` matches 0 or more chars. `.+` matches 1 or more chars. Use `.+`. And escape dots if you mean to match literal dots. Add anchors if you need to match the whole string.

Comment: Or, if you just want to match with wildcards, use `like` operator. Added https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37394439/ to the list of dupes. Note: regex IS NOT wildcards.

Comment: Except `1.2` shouldn't match `1.2.1` I guess.

Comment: I don't have a way to change the elements in B array. Source of the data is an external service. Can you help me here https://dotnetfiddle.net/NZYyx1

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim A() As String = {"1.1.1","1.1.2","1.1.3","1.2","1.3","1.4"}
Dim B() As String = {"1.1.*","1.2"}

Dim isMatch = Function(str As String, patterns() As String)
                  For Each pattern As String In patterns
                      If pattern.Contains("*") Then
                            Dim regexPattern As String = "^" & pattern.Replace(".","\.").Replace("*", "\d+") & "$"
                            If Regex.IsMatch(str, regexpattern) Then Return True
                        Else
                            If str.Equals(pattern) Then Return True
                        End If
                    Next

                    Return False
              End Function

Dim result = A.Where(Function(s) isMatch(s, B))
```

The trick here is to use Regular Expression instead of Like operator. In order to use regex, the pattern (B array items) need to be reconstructed to regular expression patterns by replacing each dots to `\.` and * to `\d+`. The `\d+` will match any digits of any length.